# Analog Thumb Stick Problems

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, analog

*Outline:*

I'm trying to work with an Arduino and Analog thumb stick to get values for a simple differential drive robot I'm working on. The [**Keyes_Sjoys Arduino Joystick Module**](http://www.plexishop.it/en/modulo-joystick-keyes-sjoys.html) I have in my possession is giving me some strange numbers however.

*Following axises Data I have:*

- X-axis range of 0 to a shaky 470-520 with a center value of 40.
- Y-axis range of a solid 4 to solid 1023 with a center value of 605.

*Problem*

I haven't used analog sensors before but it seems pretty obvious that my X-axis ranges should feel somewhat similar to the Y-axis but they don't. In addition, the X-axis hits zero way way before even coming close to the edge for its operating range.

Is my sensor plain broke (it's new), or is there some way I can recalibrate the potentiometer?

Update 1:
Wiring is the same as in this tutorial, and I used the same code, just added another analog input.
http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogReadSerial

```
void setup(){
 Serial.begin(9600); 
}
void loop(){
  int X = analogRead(A0);
  int Y = analogRead(A1);

  Serial.print("X = ");
  Serial.print(X);
  Serial.print(" Y = ");
  Serial.println(Y);
  delay(3);
}
```

Comment: One way to test it would be to measure the resistance of each axis with a multimeter to isolate if it's the joystick or a potential code / ADC problem. I'd expect the axes should be relatively similar.

Comment: How exactly have you wired the two together?

Comment: Updated with code and wiring.

Comment: Read on decoupling capacitors or refer to [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70769/arduino-incorrect-readings-from-analog-pin/294501#294501) post .

Answer (score 2):

1. Physically disconnect all connections of the module from the Arduino.
2. Then, check the resistance between the Vcc pin of the module and the actual pins *at each end* of each little potentiometer in the joystick device on the module.
3. Similarly, check resistance between the Ground pin of the module and the physical pins *at each end* of each potentiometer in the joystick device.
4. Finally check the resistance between the VRx pin and each of the *center contacts* of the little potentiometers, and similarly with VRy.

In a working module, in each case you should see a zero or nearly zero (~10 Ohms) resistance for one specific potentiometer pin from the module pin.

Almost definitely the soldering of one of the device pins on the module board is not perfect - Most likely the Vcc pin to one of the X-axis potentiometer's pins won't give you the low resistance reading expected.

Re-solder that connection on the little PCB.